# AxesLabel and Ticks with Show

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, graphics

I don't understand why AxesLabel and Ticks don't work with Show. I have the following examples. Everything works, but axes labels and ticks command don't work.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{RegionPlot[{y < x}, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Hello"}], 
   Plot[{h 2 x^2, x^1/2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {"e1", "e2"}]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Ticks -> {{None, None}}], {h, 1/2, 1}]
```

I already tried to put the command inside of the RegionPlot or Plot Command, but they don't work. I also changed axes ranges but still nothing.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plot generated by `RegionPlot` has the axes disabled in favor of `Frame`, so you'll have to either revert back to using axes, or just use the `Frame`-related options [`FrameLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) and [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html):

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  RegionPlot[{y < x}, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Hello"}],
  Plot[{h 2 x^2, x^1/2}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {"e1", "e2"}],
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  FrameTicks -> None
  ],
 {h, 1/2, 1}
 ]
```

[image]